# jQuery Delegate inside a Dialog - Selector didn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

**Updated with complete code**

I have a jQuery dialog that I want to bind some click handler events to using jQuery delegate, but somehow it doesn't work.

This works:

```
$('table.standard tbody td .delete').live('click', function() {
    alert('delete something');
});
```

This doesn't work, this calls the alert when I click **ANYWHERE** within the container, but I only wants it for the **".delete"** selector.

```
$('div.container').delegate('table.standard tbody td .delete', 'click', function() {
    alert('delete something');
});
```

**div.container** is the div inside the dialog. I've also tried to use **body** and **document** as the container, same affect.

**Here's the complete code**

This kinda work, but it doesn't get bind to the `.delete` class selector, instead, it binds to the entire row.

```
function ClientTierDialog_class() {
    var self = this;

    this.fDialogBehavior = function(dialog) {
        $(dialog).find("a.button").unbind("click").bind("click", function(e) {

            if ($(this).hasClass("cancelButton")) {
                $(dialog).dialog("close");
            }
            else if ($(this).hasClass("okButton")) {
                self.saveTier();
            }
        });
    };

    this.$dialog = null;

    this.baseOptions = {
        id: "TierDialog",
        width: 585,
        height: 600,
        className: "tier-dialog",
        header: "Create Tier",
        body: "",
        buttonText: {
            cancel: "Close",
            ok: "Save"
        },
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        fDialogBehavior: this.fDialogBehavior
    };
}

/***************************************************************
* Events
***************************************************************/

ClientTierDialog_class.prototype.openDialog = function(options) {
    var self = this;
    var tierName = options.tierName;
    var url = "Administration/GetClientTierDialog";

    this.$dialog = null;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: options,
        success: function(response) {
            var $content = $(response.html);
            var options = self.baseOptions;

            if (tierName !== undefined && tierName.length > 0) {
                options.header = "Edit Tier";
            }

            options.body = $content;
            WSOD.dialog(options);

            this.$dialog = $("div.tier-dialog");
            self.initEvents();
        },
        error: function() {
            // Handle errors
        }
    });
};

ClientTierDialog_class.prototype.delete = function() {
    $('table#addedFirms tbody tr').delegate('.delete', 'click', function() {
        alert('delete something');
    });
};

ClientTierDialog_class.prototype.initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.delete();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ClientTierDialog = new ClientTierDialog_class();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does `div.container` exist at the time the `delegate` is executed? (Is it within a DOM ready event handler?)

Comment: `div.container` exists when the dialog is opened. Thanks.

Comment: You should post more of your HTML and JS.

Comment: I've updated with the complete code... Currently, the `delete` method is kinda work but not really working... This method get executed not on the `.delete` class but the entire row click. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code its hard to be sure, but it could be that your adding the delegate before the dialog is initialized or before the `div.content` element is present. If that is the case, then the div.container may not exist and therefore will not be bound.

Try this: http://jsbin.com/itiyel/4/edit#preview

This seems to work and maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery standards are leaning towards `on` and `off` with version 1.7+:

```
$('table.standard').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    alert('delete something');
});
```

Comment: We are still on jQuery 1.5 so "on" is not an option. Thanks.

Comment: You know, upgrading jQuery is not only easy it's recommended. They have fixed a LOT of bugs since 1.5 and have made amazing performance improvements.

Comment: I understand but I can't make that decision :) FYI, we are still on ASP.NET MVC 1 when MVC 4 beta is already out!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(document).delegate('table.standard tbody td .delete', 'click', function() {
    alert('delete something');
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get $(document) to work. Tried $('body') and I got the alert call everywhere I click!